# Why not add a feature to categorize the questions personally?

Tags: feature-request

There is a great amount of information as proofs and definitions available on Math Stack Exchange. It will be really convenient if individual users can mark questions that they have read/examined separately. I feel that the ability to categorize questions as read/for later reference/etc should only improve the stack exchange experience. On the surface, I do not see any negatives to adding this feature, just that I do not have the necessary skill or editing privileges to add this feature. The only existing method similar to this feature is the adding filters part. However, it only deals with providing notifications on topics and does not help with the problem I mentioned.

Comment: You mark a quextion as "read". It gets a major edit and two new answers. Can you still call it "read"? If we clear such categorisation upon edit, what about "FFR"?

Comment: What does "FFR" mean @Lord_Farin?

Comment: @Najib For future reference.

Answer (score 5):

[You can already "favorite" questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) To do this, click the star below the voting buttons on a question. It should turn yellow, orange, or some related color depending on the site. Click again to "unfavorite", and the star will turn grey.

You can scroll through [your favorites](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117660/anonlinear?tab=favorites) in your profile.

[You cannot "favorite" answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star?lq=1)

See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/how-to-personally-separate-questions-into-separate-groups-folders?rq=1 and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/feature-request-hide-specific-questions?rq=1.

Comment: But surely there could be more than the category of favorite /not so favorite questions right? I spent time reading through a set of related questions. In the past, similar  suggestions such as a personalized grouping had been put forward. The only answer I could find says that adding this feature is difficult due to some unspecified reason.

Comment: @anonlinear Is [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/how-to-personally-separate-questions-into-separate-groups-folders?lq=1) helpful at all?

Answer (score 1):

Please note: I'm **not** speaking on behalf of Stack Exchange here, just speaking for myself.

---

I like this idea.

It's been requested a bunch of times in our annual developer survey (and on various meta sites in the past), which suggests you and me aren't the only ones that like it.

Here are a few questions for you. If you (or anyone else!) have the time to check respond to them (comments are fine, or just email me — email's in my profile), I'd be grateful:

- Would those categories be just for yourself, or would you share them with other users? Why?
- When you look at a question you categorized, would you need to see your categories? If yes, why?
- Would you want to only categorize questions, or also answers? If both: why?
- What categories would you want to use (only the ones in the original question)?

---

Note that I can't comment as to whether this is feasible, and there may be some reasons why it's not desirable that I'm not aware of.

For this reason, I'm hesitant to mark your question as [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), since it's closer to [status-i-m-thinking-about-it](/questions/tagged/status-i-m-thinking-about-it), but I hope this answer conveys the fact that we're in fact looking into it.

Comment: So maybe it's time to have [meta-tag:status-under-consideration]? :-)

Comment: Welcome to Math! I find three distinct categories of questions: (1) I want to read answers by others; (2) I want to research and answer that question when I can; (3) I want to follow up for moderation purposes. The last use case is narrow; I'll ignore it for now. Favorites work well for (1). For (2), I'm using a Trello board at present: I have a board "Stack Exchange" with lists "SO, Math, WebApps..." This works okay except there is no "add to Trello" option on desktop site - I use my phone to do that. If the desktop site used Trello API, that'd be great... Companies are related anyway.